# Autocomplete in Asp mvc & Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a textbox and i want to make an autocomplete feature

i have this view
i add the libraries but it does not respond at all

```
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter the text please" />
```

the javascript code is this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#q").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Book/AutoComplete/',
                data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                    }))
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
                failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            });
        },
    });
```

and here's the controller

```
public JsonResult AutoComplete(string prefix)
{
    var book = db.Book.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(prefix)).Select(x =>x.Name).ToList();
    return Json(book, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?

Comment: Where is your autocomplete library?

Comment: @Azim do you mean that there's a special library ?
i use the jquery-3.1.1 which provide this feature i guess

Comment: @Usman no there's not any error

Comment: can you place break point to check weather its getting to the action

Comment: @Usman my main problem is this it doesnot take the action

Comment: add this to your libraries   `<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>`

Comment: You should use `jquery-ui.js` after jQuery. @AhmadTarabeshi

Comment: What happens when you change `"{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",` to `data: { prefix: request.term },` ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to make few changes to the code

**1)** add jquery ui library by adding this into header

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

**2)**  change `data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}"` to `data: { Prefix: request.term }` remove `""` from start and end

so your code will be like this

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#q").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Book/AutoComplete/",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data,
                            function(item) {
                                return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                            }));

                    }
                });
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: Sir the ajax call does not take place i make like what you say but till now no return data

Comment: @AhmadTarabeshi check that jquery library is loaded properly and and  place alert after `source: function (request, response) { alert(); `

Comment: actually there is not any alert box

Comment: @AhmadTarabeshi its working fine i have updated my answer and try to place a break point and write something in textbox